# Integrating by substituting hyperbolic functions

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

I am trying to integrate:

$$
\int\sqrt{x^2-9}dx
$$

by substituting in:
$$
x=\sinh{t}
$$

I know you can solve it by using 
$$
x=\sec{t}
$$

But I want to solve it using the identity: 
$$
\sinh^2{x}=\frac{1}{2}(\cosh{2x}-1)
$$

Could you help?

Comment: You'd be better off using $x=3\cosh t.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=\frac{3(e^t+e^{-t})}{2}$, where $t\geq0$.

Thus,  $$\int\sqrt{x^2-9}dx=\int\sqrt{\frac{9(e^{2t}+e^{-2t}+2)}{4}-9}\cdot\frac{3(e^t-e^{-t})}{2}dt=$$
$$=\frac{9}{4}\int|e^t-e^{-t}|(e^t-e^{-t})dt=\frac{9}{4}\int(e^t-e^{-t})^2dt.$$

Can you end it now?